# Age checker Python3 18+

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I need a programm on Pyhton3 to check if the user is 18+ or not.
Input: date of the birth. in 4 types of format (25/12/2000,25-12-2000,25.12.2000,25_12_2000) 
if wrong print(wrong format)
Output: "welcome to system" or "sorry comeback when you will be 18+" 
In case you need my stupid tries:

```
from datetime import datetime, date

    def try_parsing_date(text):
        for fmt in ('%d/%m/%Y', '%d.%m.%Y', '%d-%m-%Y', '%d_%m_%Y'):
            try:
                return datetime.strftime(text,fmt)
            except ValueError:
                pass
        raise ValueError('no valid date format')
    dob  = input('Введите свой день рождения (дд/мм/гггг): ')
    try_parsing_date(dob)
```

Maybe to deal with it wit regular expressions?

````
```re_age_checker= "^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.,_](0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.,_](19|20)\d\d"```
````

Comment: Perhaps only allow a single format would be easier to deal with

Comment: Maybe the first thing that you have to do, is validate the user input, checking if the data supplied by the user is valid. After the validation, all date formats are similar, simply changes the separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your try was a good start, but you mixed up [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) with [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime); change that.

> Maybe to deal with it wit regular expressions?

This is not advisable. After the above change, we can use the result of your function `try_parsing_date` to compute the 18th birthday and simply compare that to today's date:

```
dt = try_parsing_date(dob)
import time
# compute the 18th birthday:
d = date.fromtimestamp(time.mktime((dt.year+18, dt.month, dt.day, *(0,)*6)))
if d <= date.today():
    print("welcome to system")
else:
    print("sorry comeback when you will be 18+")
```